# howto use org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient without getting ServerWebApplicationExceptions?

Tags: rest, cxf, jax-rs

I'm using Apache CXF WebClient from tomEE plus 1.7.1. 
(cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-2.6.14.jar)

I implemented a REST client that expects JSON server responses:

```
public RestClient(String aBaseUrl, String aPath) {

    this.client = WebClient.create(aBaseUrl);
    this.client.path(aPath);
    this.client.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
}

public JSONObject post(MultivaluedMap<String, String> params) {

    LOG.debug("sending POST request to: " + this.client.getCurrentURI());
    LOG.debug("POST parameters: " + PrivacyFilter.getLogLineFor(params));

    Form theForm = new Form(params);        
    JSONObject theJson;
    String resp = this.client.post(theForm, String.class);

    try {
        theJson = new JSONObject(resp);             
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        LOG.warn("got malformed answer from Server - cannot parse as JSON");
        LOG.trace(resp);
        throw new RuntimeException("got malformed answer from Server - cannot parse as JSON", e);
    }

    return theJson;
}
```

I expect that the server returns JSON data in the HTTP body.
I expect this for all HTTP status codes. Also for error cases when the code is not 2xx.

Here is my problem.
CXF seams (for any reason???) to throw a ServerWebApplicationException if the HTTP status code is >= 400. I found this piece of code inside of the WebClient implementation:

```
if (r.getStatus() >= 400 && responseClass != Response.class) {
    throw new ServerWebApplicationException(r);
}
```

What is the reason for that? Isn't it quite normal that a RESTful API answers also with codes that are greater than 400? In my opinion in this case a Exception does not seam do be a good solution.

I did not figure out how to implement my REST client using CXF. Is there a possibility to change this behavior? The Exception seams to be thrown only if responseClass != Response.class. I modified the REST client in that way:

```
public JSONObject post(MultivaluedMap<String, String> params) {

    LOG.debug("sending POST request to: " + this.client.getCurrentURI());
    LOG.debug("POST paramters: " + PrivacyFilter.getLogLineFor(params));

    Form theForm = new Form(params);        
    JSONObject theJson;

    Response respObject = this.client.post(theForm, Response.class);

    // HOW TO GET THE HTTP BODY OUT OF reps?!

    try {
        theJson = new JSONObject(resp);             
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        LOG.warn("got malformed answer from Server - cannot parse as JSON");
        LOG.trace(resp);
        throw new RuntimeException("got malformed answer from Server - cannot parse as JSON", e);
    }

    return theJson;
}
```

Here I did not find a possibility to access the HTTP body. The Response object doesn't seam to have an accessor for it. One interesting method in javax.ws.rs.core.Response is:

```
Object getEntity()
```

If I call it, I get an instance of sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream which isn't really helpful.

Do you have an idea how to implement a REST client with CXF that doesn't crash in case of HTTP status codes greater than 400?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
The problem is inside of org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient implementation in the method

```
protected <T> T readBody(Response r, Message outMessage, Class<T> cls, Type type, Annotation[] anns);
```

This method does not copy the HTTP body to the Response object if the servers returns a HTTP code greater than 400.

The newest version 2.6.16 solves this problem. The body can be extracted from the ServerWebApplicationException.

```
/* CXF does it for HTTP codes >400 
         * 
         * the original CXF (cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-2.6.14.jar) from tomEE 1.7.1 
         * does not provide the HTTP body in >400 case.
         * 
         *  We assume the usage of cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-2.6.16.jar here
         */
        catch (ServerWebApplicationException e) {

            resp = e.getMessage(); // here is the HTTP body!
        }
```

I added this to my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.16</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

This brings a lot of CXF JARs into by web app. In result tomEE does not work anymore. The CXF server parts do not work anymore.

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
...
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.tl.ThreadLocalProxy is not visible from class loader
```

In result I cannot use CXF WebClient from tomEE plus 1.7.1. Any suggestions? I will try to use apache HTTP client instead :(.